# Create alias using bash one liner

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I need to create alias for my long command, normally I would use

```
alias myLongCommand="my long command"
```

but I need to define in an online system configuration where I can only use `bash` command, I tried various combinations including:

```
bash -c 'alias myLongCommand="my long command"'
```

but unfortunately with no success, alias does not get defined.

To test success I use

```
bash -c myLongCommand
```

Comment: I think you can use `/` if your spanning multiple lines within your long command.

Comment: An alias may not be the right tool for the job -- if you used a shell function instead of an alias, you could export it (so even noninteractive bash instances would automatically have it available).

Comment: Also, aliases **are disabled by default in noninteractive shells**, so even if your alias *is* defined, that doesn't mean it'll be executed/honored.

Comment: ...anyhow, can you add more details about your use case / how you're testing for success? Are you running `bash -c 'alias myLongCommand="my long command"; myLongCommand'`, or `bash -c 'alias myLongCommand="my long command"'; myLongCommand`, or something else? Right now, we have to guess at what the behavior you're actually expecting/intending is, and so can't check answers for correctness.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy no worries. I'll keep it deleted. Your answer covers it all.

Comment: @zibi: ...btw, why the "one liner" requirement? In general, pursuing terseness above other goals tends to result in less readable, less robust code without significant compensating advantages.

Comment: Clarification about your environment would be appreciated. Even if you can only put one-liners into your configuration file, if you can export a function in a parent process of that configuration file then that limitation can be mooted (by putting that configuration *outside* the place you're currently assuming that it's obligated to reside).

Answer (score 4):

#### Short answer: Use an exported function instead

```
# define a function
myLongCommand() { my long command; }

# export that function to the environment
export -f myLongCommand

# thereafter, that function is available in subprocesses
bash -c 'myLongCommand'
```

...or, to compress the actual creation into a one-liner:

```
myLongCommand() { my long command; }; export -f myLongCommand
```

Note that the definition and export **needs to be done in a bash shell that is itself a parent process of the shell in which you intend the function to be used**. If you use `bash -c 'myLongCommand() { my long command; }; export -f myLongCommand'`, then the environment variable with the exported function lives only as long as that `bash -c` instance does -- hence, it's entirely unavailable in any subsequent command.

If you wanted this to be available for all bash shells in your login session, you could put the definition and export in `~/.bash_profile` (and log out and back in), if your system is behaving per typical defaults with respect to dotfile initialization.

#### Longer answer: Why did the original attempt fail?

Multiple reasons:

- Aliases are part of the state of an individual shell process -- there isn't a shared registry. Thus, `bash -c 'alias foo="bar"'` sets up an alias *only for that single bash instance created by the `bash -c` command*, and that alias is terminated when that command exits.
- Noninteractive shells, such as those created with `bash -c`, don't inherit aliases from their parent processes, *or* read dotfiles (by default), so they start out with their alias table empty, even if an alias is defined in the (separate) shell that's invoking them.
- Noninteractive shells, such as those created with `bash -c`, *have alias evaluation turned off by default*, as this is intended to be an interactive-use feature.

#### Longer answer: Why not an alias?

Aliases **are intended as a facility for interactive use**. Thus, they're not by default available inside noninteractive shells at all. To enable alias expansion in a noninteractive instance of bash, one needs to run:

```
shopt -s expand_aliases
```

The other issue is actually *getting that alias defined at all*. Noninteractive shells don't run dotfiles by default (the name of a dotfile to run in a noninteractive shell can be placed in the `ENV` or `BASH_ENV` environment variable to override this), so they won't have aliases defined in `~/.bashrc` present.

#### Longer answer: ...so, how *could* you use an alias?

```
# create a .env file, taking care not to fail badly if shell is not bash
# note that making noninteractive shells emit content on stderr will break some software
# ...so redirecting errors is entirely essential here, and ||: is necessary to not break
# ...any noninteractive shell (like dash or ash invocations) that doesn't support shopt
# ...when that shell is invoked with the -e argument.
cat >~/.env <<'EOF'
shopt -s expand_aliases 2>/dev/null ||: "fail gracefully w/o shopt"
alias myLongCommand="my long command" 2>/dev/null ||: "fail gracefully w/o aliases"
EOF

# point to it from your .bash_profile
cat >>~/.bash_profile <<'EOF'
export ENV=$HOME/.env
[[ -e $ENV ]] && source "$ENV"
EOF

# ...and update the already-running shell:
export ENV=$HOME/.env
source "$ENV"
```

...to do the above in one line:

```
printf '%s\n' 'shopt -s expand_aliases 2>/dev/null ||:' 'alias myLongCommand="my long command" 2>/dev/null ||:' >~/.env; printf '%s\n' 'export ENV=$HOME/.env' '[[ -e $ENV ]] && source "$ENV"' >>~/.bash_profile
```

Answer (score 2):

`bash -c` spaws a non-login, non-interactive instance of `bash`, which does not read any session startup configuration file (unlike login/interactive sessions), hence no `alias` definition available and also only exits when the command (`alias myLongCommand="my long command"` in this case) exits. So presumably you won't get the alias available.

To permanently set aliases, you should use any file that shell reads when starting the session, for interactive session, `bash` reads `~/.bashrc`. So if you put your `alias` definition there, it will available on any interactive `bash` instance:

```
echo 'alias myLongCommand="my long command"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

To make it avail;able from the running session , `source` the file:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Now from an non-interactive (and non-login) session i.e. `bash -c` you can make this `alias` available by making the shell interactive too using the `-i` option, so the `~/.bashrc` is read:

```
bash -ic 'myLongCommand'
```

Comment: `bash -c` does execute the file named by the `BASH_ENV` environment variable, though.